# groupby date and check if values across multiple columns are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with the following format

```
      X       Y        date
0   10.0     NaN  2018-12-27
1   20.0    40.0  2018-12-27
2   15.0     NaN  2018-12-24
3    NaN    20.0  2018-12-27
```

I am trying to group by date and check if a value in X is equal to the value in Y for the specific date.

I have tried the below logic but it doesn't seem work.

```
are_equal = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda g: (g.X == g.Y).sum())
df['are_equal'] = df.date.map(are_equal)
```

The desired output is a flag showing that index 1 and 3 are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with :

```
f = lambda g: g.X.fillna('no match').isin(g.Y) | g.Y.fillna('no match').isin(g.X)
df['are_equal'] = df.groupby('date', group_keys=False).apply(f)
print (df)
      X     Y        date  are_equal
0  10.0   NaN  2018-12-27      False
1  20.0  40.0  2018-12-27       True
2  15.0   NaN  2018-12-24      False
3   NaN  20.0  2018-12-27       True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not what i'm looking for. This takes into consideration the NaN values, also it checks if x is in y and not equality.

Comment: @ramez - How is necessary compare? Becaue `1` and `3` row are not equal

Comment: I am trying to capture if float values in X and Y are equal for the same date

Comment: @ramez - ok, why cannot be used `isin` ?

Comment: @ramez - Answer is changed for no match NaNs